# Producing confidence intervals for sensitivity and specificity in SAS

Tags: sas, logistic-regression, confidence-interval, roc

I am using SAS for producing ROC curves. But the "PROC LOGISTIC" does not give me the confidence-interval for sensitivity and specificity.

Does any one know if there is an option in order to produce the lower and upper band for sensitivity and specificity ?

If it is not the case, does anyone know another method ?

Thk an lot,

Answer (score 0):

when I use basic stats, I use proc freq for associations.

```
proc freq data=tempds noprint;   
 tables variable1*std_variable2 / chisq measures;
 output out=outds pchi n OR FISHER;
run;
```

The output dataset "outds" now contains *RROR*(OR), L_RROR(Lower CI), U_RROR(Upper CI). Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No, I would like to obtain the confidence interval for the ROC Curve. At each point of the curve (x,y) = (1-specificity ; sensibility) I would like to know the confidence interval for x and y.

Answer (score 0):

If `proc logistic` doesn't directly support this, you could try bootstrapping - produce many ROC plots for random samples of your data (e.g. using `proc surveyselect`) and then calculate the p5 and p95 points for each x and y value in the plot using `proc summary`. This should give a good approximation provided that you use a large enough number of samples.